# How to import all the tracked events of GA to Firebase Analytics?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-analytics, firebase-analytics

I want to import my Google Analytics for Android app data to my Firebase Analytics. I also followed the guidelines given by Google, but I am not able to get the previous GA data in FA.

Is it possible to import all the previous events, tracking of around 3 years to the new Firebase Analytics? if not, what will be the benefit of using FA as I will have to check two properties for checking tracking data?

Comment: @AL. Thanks for editing. But do you know the answer to the question?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You can import your *Firebase Analytics* into *Google Analytics* by following these steps:
https://support.google.com/analytics/answer/6392697?hl=en

but **not** the other way around.
As of now there is no way to import your *Google Analytics* data into *Firebase Analytics*.